# unity プレハブからボタンを動的に生成したい

Tags: unity3d

環境　unity　4.6

行いたいことは、プレハブ化したボタンを使用し、リストビューの中にボタンを複数自動生成したい。
下記ソースを実行しても　unity ではエラー表示はありませんが、ボタンが生成されていません。

階層は次の通り
Canvas
 -ScrollController
 --Content
 ---button
 ---button
　(中略)
 ---button

ソース
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/10de0cd126923242a571

Answer (score 0, accepted):

テストシーンを作成してみたらソースコードそのままで問題なく動作しました。ボタンが４つ生成されてラベルが「TTTT」に変更されたのを確認。スクリプト QuizMgr.cs は、「ScrollController」に AddComponentして試しました。

エラーが出てないとのことなので問題はないと思いますが念のため。
ボタンの Prefabファイルは現状のソースコードでは Resources.Load でロードされてるので、下記のようにフォルダ構成してファイルを置く必要があります。

Resources/Prefabs/AnsButton.prefab

[image: 画像]

ボタンが実は生成されていて非アクティブ（非表示）だったという可能性も疑いましたが、「ボタンが生成されていません」ということなので、Prefab自体に問題があるかと思います。いま一度、新規 Buttonを生成して Prefab作成して試してみてはどうでしょうか。